# Check & Fetch the user if exists

Tags: api, aws-appstream

When using AWS Appstream API, **How do we check if a username(*email*) exists**? And on a similar note how do we fetch that user by username?

I tried searching here on the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and while there are methods for `creation`, `deletion`, `enabling`, `disabling` users but there seems to be no specific method provided to fetch a user from the user pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** As of now we have a [`DescribeUsers`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeUsers.html) method, but again this is for fetching all (*filterable*) users but still we shall have to process all of the results to confirm a user is present or not.

==================================================

For the time being it seems the only band-aid solution is to fire a [`createUser()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUser.html) request with that username and look for the exception named `ResourceAlreadyExistsException`. But for all intents and purposes this feels tacky.

<sub>*So for want of better alternative this is the solution, once we have something better, I'll mark that answer as selected, or maybe even update this answer if I get it before others.*</sub>